# Check if message content has multiple lines in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How do I check if the message content has multiple lines in Discord.js and how do I get it?

I tried using `\n` but no results.

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'eval',
    aliases: ['evaluate'],
    desciption: 'Owner only.',
    category: 'Core',
    usage: '{prefix}eval <javascript>',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (message.author.id !== client.config.discord.ownerID) return;

        try {
            const code = args.join(' ');
            let evaled = eval(code);

            if (typeof evaled !== 'string') {
                evaled = require('util').inspect(evaled);
            }

            if (typeof evaled === 'Discord.MessageEmbed' && evaled !== null && !Array.isArray(evaled)) {
                return message.channel.send({embeds: [functions.clean(evaled)]});
            } else {
                return message.channel.send(functions.clean(evaled));
            }
        } catch (err) {
            message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${functions.clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Welcome, if you are asking a question at SO, you are expected to show an attempt at solving the problem. Or any research effort made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show your attempt at checking with `\n`. It works just fine for me

```js
message.content.includes("\n") //true if multi line
```

Here is a snippet that shows it works:

```js
var str = `single line`;
console.log(str.includes("\n"))
str = `multi
line`;
console.log(str.includes("\n"))
```